# Использование SkiaSharp в WPF с соблюдением MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Цель: разработка простого векторного редактора на *WPF* с использованием *SkiaSharp*, в частности размещение `SKElement` в окне и рисование на нем прямых линий, текста и изображений.
Вопрос: как это правильно реализовать с соблюдением MVVM?
Мои варианты:

1. Использовать привязку к событиям `PaintSurface`, `MouseEvents` и так далее через команды. Рисование будет происходить в `ViewModel`, но тогда во `ViewModel` будут использоваться классы SkiaSharp.
2. Наследовать от `SKElement` свой `Control`, прописать в нем свойства для привязки коллекции графических элементов и необходимых настроек рисования, переопределить `OnPaintSurface` и реализовать рисование в нем. Тогда во `ViewModel` будет `ObservableCollection` с элементами для отрисовки не зависящими от `SkiaSharp`, но в наследнике `SKElement` появиться много `code-behind`. Ну и в этом варианте события типа `MouseEvents` придется обрабатывать также в `code-behind` унаследованного от `SKElement` класса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скажем, в `MVVM` кто о ком знает: `View -> ViewModel -> Model`. Никто не запрещает определять логику в контролах, которая связана с работой самого контрола. Рисование как раз-таки и нужно реализовывать в контроле, в нём даже можно напрямую обратиться ко вью модели и присвоить нужные изменения, но не передавать во `ViewModel` ссылки на себя или свои части, только данные обновить можно.

Пробрасывать во `ViewModel` части от `View` точно неправильно. В `Code Behind` представления `(View)` должно быть всё, что работает так или иначе со `View`. `Code Behind` представления это не изгой, в котором ничего нельзя писать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я так и стал делать, но в какой-то момент меня одолели сомнения. Теперь могу продолжать с чистой совестью))